# Continuous strictly increasing function is absolutely continuous iff set of infinite derivative maps to measure zero set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity

If $u:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and strictly increasing, prove that $u$ is absolutely continuous iff it maps $E:=\{x\in[a,b]:u'(x)=\infty\}$ into a set of measure 0.

This question came from http://www.ams.org/bookstore/pspdf/gsm-105-prev.pdf , page 10.

For the forwards direction, we can show that $E$ is of measure 0, so $f(E)$ must be also of measure 0.

I am unable to prove the reverse direction. I tried proving the Lusin N property but $[a,b]\setminus E$ may also contain points that $u'$ has finite left derivative but infinite right derivative (which is of measure 0, but what about its image?). The idea was as follows:

For any null set $N$, $N=(N\cap E)\cup\bigcup_n(N\cap E_n)\cup (N\cap R)$, where $E_n=\{x\in[a,b]:u'(x)<n\}$ and $R=\{x\in[a,b]:u'(x)\text{ does not exist and is not }\infty\}$. So $f(N)=f(N\cap E)\cup\bigcup_n f(N\cap E_n)\subseteq f(E)\cup\bigcup_n f(N\cap E_n)\cup f(N\cap R)$. All are null sets except for the last term.

Comment: It may depend on what textbook you are relying on for the proof of the Lebesgue differentiation theorem.  Many proofs show that if $u:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ is continuous and strictly increasing and if $$N=\left\{x\in [a,b]: \underline D u(x) < \overline Du(x) \right\}$$ then $$m(N)=m(u(N))=0.$$ That shows that, except for a set $N$ with measure zero and with $u(N)$ also of measure zero $u$ has a finite or infinite derivative everywhere.  Thus if you add in the hypothesis here about the infinite derivative you have Lusin's condition (N) on all of $[a,b]$.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson Are there any free textbooks/ lecture notes which give this result? Or do you have any hint?

Comment: This is implicit in the proof that we give for the Lebesgue differentiation theorem in Bruckner, Bruckner, Thomson *Real Analysis* which, oddly enough, is available for free download at our web site classicalrealanalysis.com.  There must be others.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson Nice, thanks for the free reference! I can't understand some of the notation used, and I'm not sure what are the prerequisite theorems for that chapter. But I hope it will be useful to someone else in the future.

Comment: My point, then, is that you do need to come up with a proof somehow that the set $u(N)$ has measure zero. I don't think that any manipulations will give you an answer if all you have available to work with is that (i)  $u'$ exists almost everywhere and (ii) $u'=\infty$ on a set that maps by $u$ to a measure zero set.

Comment: May be it is not correct because the Cantor functions is not  AC and the set of its non-differentiability is of measure 0.